# Is my scene going to stay in memory forever

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a bunch of classes that retain an instance of the scene and I'm starting to think this is going to cause memory management issues for me.

So I have Scene1, Scene2 and a HelperClass that has a property that retains the scene.

When I switch from Scene1 to Scene2 I want everything to be disposed.

I started thinking though am I going to have to manually release the helper class before I call the director to change the scene?

The helper class is retained by a layer that is a child of the scene.

The layer also has a property reference to the scene as a ccnode.

Am I doing this wrong?  What is the best way to arrange these things so the memory gets free correctly.

The helper classes do things like creating bullets and adding them to the scene.

I have a similar setup with CCSprites that only exist at the scene level.  I keep references to them in the helper classes.

Comment: One of my early lines of thoughts is that all these Helper classes should be CCNodes and I should not keep property references to anything from cocos2d i should instead add the ccnode to the parent class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you add something to a container, a scene or spritesheet or whatever, release it, the container keeps a ref to it, then when you dispose of the container, it will be released.
Scene will not be released if you call push scene, only if you run a new one or call the replaceScene method of CCDirector.

Comment: I made a retaining loop between parent and child.  The answer was not to retain the parent object property and do an assign instead.